# Two companies, one internet connection

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan, fiber

We're moving into a new building with two other tenants in the next few months and we'll be splitting the costs for a single fibre connection running 10 Mbps.  The ISP will be providing a four IP's for each company.  Each company has runs their own internal networks and need to know what additional hardware is needed to make this work efficiently.

We want to be able to manage the bandwidth for each company to ensure availability for everyone and to adjust the split cost accordingly.

Options?  Specific hardware recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on managing the bandwith for each company then you (or your ISP) needs to put a router at your location with QoS shaping of traffic.

The next step is firewall. There are different options to choose from:

- 4 different physical firewalls (best security and segregation)
- 1 physical firewall, 4 security contexts (virtual firewalls)
- 1 physical firewall, 5 interfaces (outside, company A, company B etc)

The last option could give you traffic shaping at the firewall level, but it's far more dangerous if each company has their own admin who wants to manage the firewall.

Internally you'll either need a completely separate physical network for each company, or use VLAN's to logically seperate the networks.

Answer (score 0):

Geta cheap router / firewall. A Mikrotik 450 or 590 should be enough. The 450 is less than 200 USD.

It isa firewall /  router combo that you can nicely use to ditribute thigns further.